# What is Red,Yellow and Green Box testing?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, gui, api-testing

I can find the explanations for black box and white box testing, but couldn't find any better explanation on Red box, Yellow box and Green box testing.

**Red Box is User Acceptance testing.**
**Grey Box is Combination of White and Black box.**
What about the Yellow and Green Box?

can anyone say with appropriate examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As of my reading-

**Red-Box Testing:**
It is nothing but a Protocol testing.
User / Client can apply any techniques to accept the project. 
They will apply white box or grey box or black box for accepting the project. 
So we are calling the user acceptance testing as a red box testing.

**Yellow box Testing:** 
Yellow box testing is checking against
the warning messages(Warning messages Testing). The system properly throwing the
warning messages or not?

**Green Box Testing:** 
Takes external perspective of the test
object to derive the test cases, determine whether the
system is environment friendly and also not having any
social implications along with the defined set of requirements.

Comment: Hi Bharat, Your information is good. Can you please elaborate green box testing

Answer (score 2):

Yellow box testing-
It is a message level testing. We can say that yellow box testing is the validation of alert messages. User can test that whether the application is correctly providing the alert messages. This is widely used technique in manual testing these days.

Green Box testing-
It is a testing process that exercises a software system's coexistence with others by taking multiple integrated systems that have passed system testing as input and test their required interactions.

Red box testing - Red box testing is widely termed as Acceptance testing. The name says that if the system is not accepted then it is a red box and useless.

These all techniques are part of manual testing services and are used with other software qa services like Black box, Grey box and White box.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this question and answers, you can find some explanations in there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620990/what-is-red-box-yellow-box-and-green-box-testing

Comment: I still dispute those answers.  I've never worked anywhere, or worked with anyone who has worked anywhere that those terms were actually used.  I suspect that someone, somewhere used them once or that they ended up on an ISEB test paper to trap people.   However, after writing this, I shall continue with my mauve box testing, which is where you test newly delivered code whilst eating cake but NOT drinking coffee.

Answer (score 1):

**Yellow Box Testing** includes the Acceptance Testing Techniques 
while **Green Box Testing** contains the Release Testing Techniques.

Comment: what is difference between Red Box and Yellow box testing?

Comment: Red box testing is for Error Message Testing while Yellow box is for Warning messages Testing